# How can I encode only the first level to JSON with a nested PHP object

Tags: php, json, cakephp

My environment is CakePHP 3.8, but it is a basic question that is not necessarily Cake specific.

**Background:**

Let's say we have a nested object. 
On the first level there are articles, on the second level the comments. 
The articles need the comments for certain calculations (e.g. for the number of comments in the article or for Rating calculations). The comments should not be sent to the browser (as JSON).

So I only need the first level (articles) in the JSON structure.

`json_encode` renders the complete PHP structure in a JSON object (including the comments). There is a `depth` parameter, but it specifies when `json_encode` failed, not when `json_encode` should stop.

Is there a way to convert only the first level of the PHP object to JSON?

Of course I am aware that it seems somehow strange, because "comments" is a key on the first level. 
Maybe there is a way to render only scalar types to JSON.

**1st Change**

Maybe I explained it too superficially.

In my cake controller:

```
$erticles = $ this->Articles->find ('all', ['contain' => ['Comments']]);
$this->set ('articles', $ articles);
$this->set ('_serialize', ['articles']);
$this->viewBuilder()->setClassName ('Json');
```

`$articles` is now a `resultSet` object, but this is not important because it can be iterated. Let's say it's an array.

a

```
var_dump ($articles->toArray())
```

would look like this:

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Article)#7749 (5) { 
    ["id"]=> int(66040)
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Test1" 
    ["comments"]=> array(2) { 
      [0]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Entity)#7749 (2) {
        ["id"]=> int(66041)
        ["comments"]=> string(8) "Comment1" 
      }
      [1]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Entity)#7749 (2) {
        ["id"]=> int(66042)
        ["comments"]=> string(8) "Comment1" 
      }
    }
    ["count_comments"]=> 2 
    ["created"]=> "2018-10-10 20:29:13.000000" 
  }
  [1]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Article)#7749 (5) { 
    ["id"]=> int(66043)
    ["name"]=> string(5) "Test2" 
    ["comments"]=> array(2) { 
      [0]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Entity)#7749 (3) {
        ["id"]=> int(66044)
        ["comments"]=> string(8) "Comment3" 
      }
      [1]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Entity)#7749 (2) {
        ["id"]=> int(66045)
        ["comments"]=> string(8) "Comment4" 
      }
      [2]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Entity)#7749 (2) {
        ["id"]=> int(66046)
        ["comments"]=> string(8) "Comment5" 
      }
    }
    ["count_comments"]=> 3 
    ["created"]=> "2018-10-10 20:29:13.000000" 
  }
}
```

(This is just an example that I typed by hand. It is intended to clarify the facts. I cannot display the original structure because it is too large and the application does not contain two, but 5, levels. The problem (and the solution) will be the same.

**@Nick:**
Thanks for the quick comment, iterate and delete the object is not the solution, because some of the properties are virtual. This means that when I access count_comments, the comments are counted; So they must still exist at the time of building the first level.

As a result, I wish:

```
[
   {
      "id":66040,
      "name":"Test1",
      "count_comments":2,
      "created":"2018-10-10 20:29:13.000000"
   },
   {
      "id":66043,
      "name":"Test2",
      "count_comments":3,
      "created":"2018-10-10 20:29:13.000000"
   }
]
```

I hope I could express myself a little more clearly now

Comment: `unset($obj->comments); echo json_encode($obj);`?

Comment: Can you show an example of the data and what you want the result to look like.  You would normally be expected to make some attempt at it, so also add what you have tried so far.

Comment: When a question starts with _"Let's say we have..."_ and then no real examples, I tend to skip the question and move on. Instead of posting an abstract explanation of your code, you should create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the code (or a thought through example of the code) you have questions about/issues with. That will make it much easier for us to help you and reduce the amount of questions and possible misunderstandings.

Comment: `This is just an example that I typed by hand` ... I dont think so

Comment: @GetSet can you believe ...

Comment: @GetSet - I don't think it really matters :-) The OP has clarified the problem and that was important part.

Comment: I may not have understood the clarification @bestprogrammerintheworld. At end day, some code (as in a loop, but think similar to a "reduce") would be needed. I suppose OP including the var_dumps was insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want? I would to try to create a new array based on your original array and on that newly created array - do a json_encode.

Something like this...

```
<?php
$first_level_arr = array();
foreach($articles->toArray() as $arr) {
    $first_level_arr[] = array(
                            $arr['id'], 
                            $arr['name'], 
                            $arr['count_comments'], 
                            $arr['created']
                         );
}

$result_json = json_encode($first_level_arr);
```

If you don't these static keys (above), you could use `array_keys`. (but then you get ALL keys on the first level (including comments key)).

```
foreach($articles->toArray() as $key=>$arr) {
    $include_keys = array_keys($arr);
    foreach($include_keys as $firstlevel_key) {
        $first_level_arr[$key][$firstlevel_key] = $arr[$firstlevel_key];
    }
}

//If you want to remove a specific key you could do like this:
//(In this case removal of the comments key)
foreach($first_level_arr as &$fla) {
    unset($fla['comments']);
}

$result_json = json_encode($first_level_arr);
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but a static one. I would have to update the code whenever I change the model (e.g. add columns). But I think I will use it as a work around.

Comment: aha. sorry. I thought it would be static. I will give you a better updated answer then. Wait a while.